# Tring to make more specific regex code

Tags: regex

I understand the use of ^ for making a string specific regex, but I'm not sure why my code isn't picking it up. I've messed with changing [] and (), but with no luck :/

```
/.*^([\/php|.html|.css])$/
```

Tested with

```
wss://worker.com/sdfsd.css
wss://worker.com/php
html://worker.com/sdfsd/bob.html
```

My current non-working example; https://regex101.com/r/qkupPT/1

Comment: Can you please describe in words what you would like your regex to match. I can guess that you want a string that ends with `/php`, `.html`, or `.css` but without some clear direction it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: I thought my "tested with" examples would be enough?

Comment: I would suggest `.*(\/php|\.html|\.css)`.

Comment: Hmm okay, that works, I didnt need a "^" afterall

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you understand what your current regex is doing. The `^` is for the start of a string. The `[]` creates a character class which allows one of the characters in it to be present (or a range if the `-` is used, e.g. `a-z`, `0-9`). For multiple characters from the character class to be allowed you'd add a quantifier after the closing `]`, either `+` for 1 or more character, or `*` for 0 or more (meaning none of the characters are required). Something like:

```
[.\/](php|css|html)$
```

Should allow for the three examples you've listed. That allows for the string to end with a `.` or a `/` and then either `css`, `php`, or `html`. Also note a `.` outside a character class needs to be escaped otherwise it is a single non new-line character.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/qkupPT/2